# Retrieve home_timeleine of any twitter user

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, oauth, tweepy

I'm trying to create an application that hides child abuse posts by a Twitter user. For that, I need to get a home timeline of a user and then analyse their tweets. I used Python code and tried to retrieve home timeline of any user but that code retrieves home timeline of the Twitter user who I have used to create twitter dev application. Below is the code:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in 
tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline,screen_name='@OKpin').items(20):
print (status._json['text'])
```

I want to change `screen_name` of the user and retrieve their home timelines. How do I modify the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Before printing the output of `status._json['text']` you can assign that value to another variable and replace the text "@OKpin" with something else.